Customize SharePoint Initiation form to add Attachment?
So, I am building out the program SharePoint page to better enhance the ability to perform our job. One of the things I am trying to do is move from Excel to SharePoint list for asset tracking. I am limited to SharePoint 2016/online hybrid environment. From my understanding is I can use an Initiation form with workflow to ask the questions to people for data, but I have not tried out the InfoPath form side due to needing InfoPath designer installed.
I created a sample initiation form and was able to flow it to the list I pointed it at using SharePoint designer. The function I am missing still that I can't figure out is adding the ability to attach attachments to the initiation form when asking for the data. I did see the option to add pictures or a URL, but not the ability to attach documents.
